# What is Link baiting

Tags: seo, backlinks, sitelinks, link-building, seo-competition-analysis

What is Link baiting and how can I use it in seo OFF-Page Activities.
Is it really useful for SEO Link building?
Help me for increase rankings

Answer (score 2):

Link bait is content on your site that is created to get other sites to link to it. This is generally high quality, shareable content which other users deem to be created by a knowledgeable and reputable source. Yes, creating quality, linkable content is essential for SEO and gaining quality, natural links to your site is too.There are certain types of content which often attract a lot of links such as games, infographics and whitepapers. The next step is then to effectively market your content through the correct channels, targeting the correct influencers. I recommend reading around the topic further in [Search Engine Land](http://searchengineland.com/library/link-building/link-building-linkbait) and [Moz](https://moz.com/blog/10-extraordinary-examples-of-effective-link-bait) as the topic is huge and one size does not fit all.